# SQL Server : compare two CTE Tables

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I would like to compare two CTES tables. The purpose of this is that i would like to see which PersonKey(PK) exists in another CTE table i have created. So i could match the data after.

```
WITH cte1 AS
(
    SELECT DISTINCT 1.PERSON_CODE,la.AIM
    FROM [PEOPLE_UNITS] 1
    INNER JOIN PEOPLE p ON p.PERSON_CODE = 1.PERSON_CODE
    INNER JOIN AIMS la on la.person_code = 1.PERSON_CODE
    WHERE la.AIM = 'Delta'
),
cte2 AS
(
    SELECT p.PERSON_CODE,FES_UINS_INSTANCE_CODE
    FROM [ebslive].[dbo].[PEOPLE_UNITS] 1
    INNER JOIN dbo.PEOPLE p ON p.PERSON_CODE = 1.PERSON_CODE
    INNER JOIN dbo.PEOPLE_UIO PUIO ON 1.UIO_ID = puio.UIO_ID
    INNER JOIN dbo.LEARNER_AIMS la on la.person_code = 1.PERSON_CODE
    INNER JOIN dbo.UNIT_INSTANCE_OCCURRENCES UIO ON UIO.UIO_ID = la.UIO_ID
    INNER JOIN dbo.UNIT_INSTANCES UI ON UI.FES_UNIT_INSTANCE_CODE = uio.FES_UINS_INSTANCE_CODE
)
```

Comment: Please show what results you want.  "Compare" is not clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

THis will do it:

```
Select PERSON_CODE from cte a where exists
(
select 1 from cte2 b where a.PERSON_CODE  = b.PERSON_CODE 
)
```